# AWS Lambda and setting cookie

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, cookies, cross-domain

I have a problem with setting a cookie on the response from the lambda function.

There are two pages (uploaded on s3 bucket) - login and validate.

On my login page I do some calls to 3rd api and at the end of that I return a cookie.

```
{
  statusCode: 200,
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'HERE GOES DOMAIN WITH LOGIN.HTML AND VALIDATE.HTML FILES',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,X-Amz-Security-Token,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Requested-With,Accept,Access-Control-Allow-Methods,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS',
    'Set-Cookie': "sess_id=key;Expires=SOME_VAL;Path=/"
  }
}
```

I do see that cookie in developers tool in response headers but its not getting set up for some reason. `document.cookie` result with empty string.

So I set that up manually but when I do another reqeust on my second page (validate) to API gateway (lambda for validating that session) the session is not included in the request headers.

I use fetch web api and `credentials:"include"` with each request but without any success.

Any tips?
Thanks.

Comment: The HTTP response header from the server is named `Set-Cookie`, not `Cookie`. The HTTP request header subsequently sent by the client to the server is named `Cookie`.

Comment: @jarmod my bad.. I had Set-Cookie instead of Cookie. I just copied it wrongly. Issue is still the same as decribed. Edited the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Your response looks correct.
Cookies are only going to go to the domains from which they came.
Are you sure your cookie came from the same domain?
Cookie won't be saved if for example cookies came from localhost:4001, the frontend is localhost:4000.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32664196)